# How to have an HTML input field appear when the value 'other' is selected with PHP

Tags: php, html

What I am trying to figure out is how to have an html *input* field appear when the value of *other* is selected from a dropdown menu. Right now the values for the dropdown list are coming from the results of a MySQL DB query, which works, but I can not seem to figure out how to get an input to appear when I select the other option.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT type FROM Dropdown_Service_Type"); // Run your query

        echo '<select name="service_type">'; // Open your drop down box

        echo '<option value="NULL"></option>';
        // Loop through the query results, outputing the options one by one
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
         echo '<option value="'.$row['type'].'">'.$row['type'].'</option>';
        }
         echo '<option value="Other">Other</option>';
        echo '</select>';// Close your drop down box
```

Comment: have you tried using jQuery?

Comment: when does "`the other option`" get introduced? nothing in the code sample appears to relate to that..

Comment: @MarkVincentManjac I have never used jQuery, and would have no idea how to start. Is that the only way?

Comment: @SamOnela the 'other' option, comes from the MySQL database, I just edited the code so it is a separate option

Comment: I'm not gonna say it is the only way but it will be very easy and effective if you use jQuery.

Comment: @MarkVincentManjac not to be a burden, but could you give me an example code on how I would do that, and also, would I need any special requirements to use jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use javascript, like in the example below. We can add an [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) field and have it hidden by default, using the *style* attribute: 
    `<input name='otherInput' id='otherInput' type="text" style="display: none" />`

```js
var otherInput;
function checkOptions(select) {
  otherInput = document.getElementById('otherInput');
  if (select.options[select.selectedIndex].value == "Other") {
    otherInput.style.display = 'block';
    
  }
  else {
    otherInput.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<select onchange="checkOptions(this)" name="service_type" id="service_type">
  <option value="NULL"></option>
  <option value="43">43</option>
  <!-- other options from your database query results displayed here -->
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<!-- the style attribute here has display none initially, so it will be hidden by default -->
<input name='otherInput' id='otherInput' type="text" style="display: none" />
```

There are 3rd party libraries like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/), AngularJS, PrototypeJS, etc.,  which can be used to make the code simpler by adding shortcut methods for DOM manipulation (though you should read [this post](https://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery/why-not/)). For example, with jQuery, using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (for the event handler binding), [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) for the input display toggling, etc:

```js
var otherInput;
var serviceTypeInput = $('#service_type');
serviceTypeInput.on('change', function() {
  otherInput = $('#otherInput');
  if (serviceTypeInput.val() == "Other") {
    otherInput.show();
  } else {
    otherInput.hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="service_type" id="service_type">
  <option value="NULL"></option>
  <option value="43">43</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<input name='otherInput' id='otherInput' type="text" style="display: none" />
```

Comment: The part of the code where there is var, is that JS? And where would I put that in the code?

Comment: it needs to go into a [script tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) (i.e. `<script>...</script>`) so in PHP you could add that to an echo statement - e.g. `echo "<script type=\"text/javascript">var...` keep in mind that if you use double quote to delimit it, then any double quotes (e.g. `type="text/javascript"` will need to be escaped... you could also use [heredoc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) to not worry about escaping the quotes...

Comment: to be honest, you so lost me, I tried adding the code and adding an echo before every line with the double quotes and now the php will not work.

Comment: okay - please take a look at [this phpfiddle example](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/f44z-f0iy) - hopefully that helps you see the examples in PHP

Comment: can you please check out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43551976/dynamic-drop-down-change-input-tag-with-js-and-html. I tried to modify the code I used from you before, but I can not get it to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#sample').change(function() {
    var val = this.value; // get the value of the select.
    if (val == 'other') { // if the value is equal to "other" then append input below the select
      $('html').append('<input type="text" id="inputOther"/>');
    } else { // else then remove the input
      $('#inputOther').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sample">
  <option value="test1">test1</option>
  <option value="test2">test2</option>
  <option value="test3">test3</option>
  <option value="other">other</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I suggest always elaborating on what your code does, and why. Particularly when dealing with someone who has stated that they have no knowledge of jquery

Comment: In addition to what Jon P said, I wouldn't suggest an OP use a library like jQuery unless it was tagged or they specifically asked in the question how to use a library like that (which might get it flagged as off-topic)...